# What is the appropriate way to use BCE loss with ResNet outputs?

Tags: pytorch

The title explains the overall problem, but for some elaboration:

I'm using `torchvision.models.resnet18()` to run an anomaly detection scheme. I initialize the model by doing:

```
net = torchvision.models.resnet18(num_classes=2)
```

since in my particular setting `0` equals normal samples and `1` equals anomalous samples.

The output from my model is of shape `(16, 2)` (batch size is 16) and labels are of size `(16, 1)`. This gives me the error that the two input tensors are of inappropriate shape.

In order to solve this, I tried something like:

```
>>> new_output = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)
```

Which gives me the appropriate shape, but running `loss = nn.BCELoss(new_output, labels)` gives me the error:

```
RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

What is the appropriate way for me to approach this issue? Thanks.

### Edit

I've also tried using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` as well, but am getting the same RuntimeError.

More specifically, I tried `nn.CrossEntropyLoss(output, label)` and `nn.CrossEntropyLoss(output, label.flatten())`.

Comment: You should use `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(output, label)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use BCELoss, the output shape should be `(16, 1)` instead of `(16, 2)` even though you have two classes. You may consider reading this excellent [writing](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-binary-cross-entropy-log-loss-a-visual-explanation-a3ac6025181a) to under binary cross-entropy loss.

Since you are getting output from `resnet18` with shape `(16, 2)`, you should rather use [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) where you can give `(16, 2)` output and label of shape `(16)`.

You should use `CrossEntropyLoss` as follows.

```
loss_crit = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = loss_crit(output, label)
```

where output = `(16, 2)` and label = `(16)`. Please note, the label should contain either 0 or 1.

Please see the example provided (copied below) in the official documentation.

```
>>> loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
>>> input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
>>> target = torch.empty(3, dtype=torch.long).random_(5)
>>> output = loss(input, target)
>>> output.backward()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've also tried using cross entropy loss, but am getting the same RuntimeError regarding `bool` values being ambiguous. I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: Don't perform `argmax` if you are using CrossEntropyLoss.

Comment: Thanks! Using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss(output, labels.flatten())` runs fine. :)